# Nothing found for wp-login php - Wordpress Error

Tags: php, wordpress, http-status-code-404

As i have been stuck at the point where i get this error in wordpress admin side. My front side (ie. http://example.com/) is working well.

But when i try to open admin side (ie. http://example.com/wp-admin) its give me below errors.

**Error 404 / 404 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR**

```
We are sorry, the page you are looking for does not exist
404 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
You might try to use our Site Search or Back to Home Page.
```

I tried lots of things but can not success to get rid of this issue, Can anyone please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the list of possibilities approaches infinite.

Comment: @Dagon: Then how to come out from this issue??

Comment: new install, update, was it ever working, how has it installed if new, where, what's at the location specified, what's in .htacess, anything in he error logs .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possibilities that will generate  404 error.

- The folder is missing
- `.htaccess` got screwed up

Comment: Yes, have problem with .htaccess file, there are code to deny all users to get logged In. Thankx